# pyramid middleware call to mssql stored procedure - no response

Tags: python-2.7, stored-procedures, pyramid, pymssql

From a pyramid middleware application I'm calling a stored procedure with pymssql. The procedure responds nicely upon the first request I pass through the middleware from the frontend (angularJS). Upon subsequent requests however, I do not get any response at all, not even a timeout.

If I then restart the pyramid application, the same above described happens again.

I'm observing this behavior with a couple of procedures that were implemented just yesterday. Some other procedures implemented months ago are working just fine, regardless of how often I call them.

I'm not writing the procedures myself, they are provided for.

From what I'm describing here, can anybody tell where the bug should be hiding most probably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was rather trivial. Within one object instance, I was calling two different stored procedures without closing the connection after the first call. That caused a pending request or so in the MSSQL-DB, locking it for further requests.